# Which Version of ASP.net MVC I'm having?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This seems really silly but;

How can I know which version of ASP.net MVC I've on my system. I've tried Help->About in Visual Studio (2008) but its not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the New Project window, look at the installed templates under web. ASP.NET MVC Web Application is 1.0 (and will say so in the description). The same goes for ASP.NET MVC 2.

[alt text http://dusda.com/files/projectswindow.png](http://dusda.com/files/projectswindow.png)

Comment: Thanks dude, I had opened New Project dialog but then it struck me which version it will be? It comes right under Templates list and says "A project for creating an application using the ASP.NET MVC framework (1.0) (.NET Framework 3.5)". So I'm off to download new version first.

Comment: No problem. I should also mention that MVC 1 and 2 are completely separate libraries, so you should have no problem running them side by side.

Comment: I knew I should have posted screenshots if I wanted my answer to be selected...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs, I see "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 1.0" on my machine...

I also see the following comment between the project type selection window and the filename box when I go to start a new MVC project:

"A project for creating an application using the ASP.NET MVC framework (1.0) (.NET Framework 3.5)"

Comment: What's will be a pain? Checking the Add/Remove Programs list?